# Import CSV to MYSQL from a JAVA project folder

Tags: java, mysql, sql, csv

I am developing a private web application in Java with a mySQL database. I am having one problem and a question.

As IDE I am using IntelliJ. Now I am at a point where I have to implement a way to insert a lot of data behind each other, but that takes a lot of time. Therefore I  thought of prepping a csv file, temporally store it in the project folder and bulk insert it in the DB.

I've found the option `LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/products.csv' INTO TABLE products;`
And for the path I've used

```
URL url = ClassLoader.class.getResource("sample.csv");
String path = url.getPath();
```

But the url is always null, even though the class and the csv are in the same folder. What am I doing wrong?

Since I can't get to the next step I wasn't able to test the LOAD DATA way. Is my way possible at all?  Or do you have a better suggestion to me.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you want to use LOAD DATA then you must have FILE privilege and put the file to be loaded into the directory specified in @@secure_file_priv.

Comment: please use the following form `foo.bar.Baz.class.getResource("xyz.txt");` to get resource relative to some package; or the following equivalent `foo.bar.Baz.class.getClassLoader().getResource("foo/bar/xyz.txt");`